# Python match '.\' at start of string

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I need to identify where some powershell path strings cross over into Python.

How do I detect if a path in Python starts with `.\`  ??

Here's an example:

```
import re

file_path = ".\reports\dsReports"

if re.match(r'.\\', file_path):
    print "Pass"
else:
    print "Fail"
```

This Fails, in the debugger it lists

```
  expression = .\\\\\\
   string = .\\reports\\\\dsReports
```

If I try using replace like so:

```
import re

file_path = ".\reports\dsReports"
testThis = file_path.replace(r'\', '&jkl$ff88')

if re.match(r'.&jkl$ff88', file_path):
    print "Pass"
else:
    print "Fail"
```

the `testThis` variable ends up like this:

```
testThis = '.\\reports&jkl$ff88dsReports'
```

Quite agravating.

Comment: Why can't you use "if '.\' == file_path[0:2]" or "if '.\' in file_path"?

Comment: As a rule, always use raw strings for Windows paths, not just for regex patterns. In this case, the `\r` in your path is converted to a carriage return, but there are many other combinations that would have similar problems (e.g. `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n` `\t`, `\v`, `\x`, and on Python 3 `str` and Python 2 `unicode` literals, `\u`, `\U`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because `\r` is an escape sequence. You will need to either escape the backslashes by doubling them, or use a raw string literal like this:

```
file_path = r".\reports\dsReports"
```

And then check if it starts with `".\\"`:

```
if file_path.startswith('.\\'):
    do_whatever()
```

Comment: Or starts with `r".\"`

Comment: That gives me `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: @donkopotamus: Raw string literals can't end in a single backslash; the backslash prevents the `"` from being interpreted as the end of the literal.

Comment: @user2357112: You can implicit concat raw and non-raw literals though, e.g. `r'.' '\\'`.

Comment: @wackamadoodle3000  You had half a good idea, i was able to figure it out from that. I hadn't considered "rawing" the string I was comparing too.  I'm editing your response to be correct.  Please approve edit and I will mark right.

Comment: @JamieMarshall: "Starts with" isn't `re.match`. "Starts with" is `.startswith`. If you want a regex, `r'^\.\\'` would do; `'.\\.*'` matches an arbitrary non-newline character followed by zero or more literal periods.

Comment: @user2357112 - I see.  I can't actually use that solution because my string is coming from powershell and it doesn't come in equal to r".\reports\dsReports" where as the regex solution can be made to work.  Either way i'll mark the question answered. This solution is actually the first thing I tried.  Also, your regex doesn't work because Python has trouble matching strings that end in '\'.  Thus r'^\.\\' throws an error.  That's why i need to look for a random character to match with after '.\\'

Comment: @JamieMarshall: My regex matches what it should in [my tests](https://ideone.com/PvuvWV). Your regex matches things it shouldn't, like `"potatos"`.